# Set a default location when launching the android sdk

Tags: android-emulator

I'm working on an android application which uses the GPS location to predict Sun rise / set (amoung other things).  Getting this right requires both timezone and location to be set.

The timezone is easy, and can be set inside the emulator, but is there a way to set the default start location when an emulator starts up?  Having to manually push the geo to something near me is something I'd like to avoid if possible.